# Printing Receipt in Pos Application

Tags: c#, windows

I am working in POS application using windows. I am getting problem with writing the receipt. Here format is missing. Can any one help me to solve this.

Comment: your receipt format please

Comment: what is the problem and which language ? details will really be appreciated.thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can make a table in C# and add the data into each box while parsing the data.

```
using System;
using System.Data;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Get the DataTable.
        DataTable table = GetTable();
        // ... Use the DataTable here with SQL.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This example method generates a DataTable.
    /// </summary>
    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
        return table;
    }
}
```

and then make the border of the table invisible.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Receipt form and place a grid on it.
Create as many Grid rows and columns as needed with labels in each cell.
Assign the width and height of the columns and rows respectively.

This way all the columns will be properly aligned.